# How to copy select list value from a webform submisison into select list field new node?

Tags: 7, nodes, webforms, rules

This is the scenario:

A webform with the following fields

```
Question -> Textfield
Category -> Select options (Listbox) Listing vocabulary HETCAT
```

A content type Question with these fields

```
Title
Category -> Term reference listing vocabulary HETCAT
```

Once the webform is submitted i create a new question node.
Everything works fine, the Question field of the webform is the new Question node title, but i can not see the way to copy the category selected on the webform to the new node

Thanks in advance

This is the export rule code

```
{ "rules_submissions_to_node" : {
"LABEL" : "Submissions to node",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules" ],
"ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "webform_has_id" : {
      "form_id" : [ "form_id" ],
      "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-140" : "webform-client-form-140" } }
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "node",
        "param_type" : "het_question",
        "param_title" : [ "node:title" ],
        "param_author" : [ "user" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "new_question" : "New question" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "new-question:title" ], "value" : "[data:question-value]" } },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "new-question:field-month" ],
      "value" : [ "site:current-date" ]
    }
  },
  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "new-question" ], "immediate" : 1 } },
  { "mail_to_users_of_role" : {
      "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } },
      "subject" : "New question to approve",
      "message" : "[new-question:title]\r\n\r\n\u003Ca href=\u0022[new-question:edit-url]\u0022\u003EEdit to publish it\u003C\/a\u003E\r\n",
      "from" : "[site:name]"
    }
  },
  { "node_unpublish" : { "node" : [ "new-question" ] } }
]}}
```

Comment: How do you achieve node_save? some code would be helpful

Comment: of course, thanks for the help. I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally i figure it out how to solve it.

I'm using [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module

Just need to add an `Execute custom PHP code` action and set the value like this

```
// $new_question is my new node.
// $data['components']['category'] is my webform listbox component.
// $new_question->field_category is my taxonomy reference field select list.

$tid = substr($data['components']['category']['value'][0],4,2);
$new_question->field_category['und'][0]['tid'] = $tid;
```